# C# can I Scrape a webBrowser control for links?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, hyperlink, scrape

I'm currently learning C# and its fun so far, but I have hit a roadblock.

I have a program that can scrape a webpage inside the web browser control for information.

So far I can get HTML

```
HtmlWindow window = webBrowser1.Document.Window;
string str = window.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
richTextBox1.Text = (str.ToString());
```

And Text

```
HtmlWindow window = webBrowser1.Document.Window;
string str = window.Document.Body.OuterText;
richTextBox1.Text = (str.ToString());
```

I have tried to scrape and display links like this

```
HtmlWindow window = webBrowser1.Document.Window;
string str = window.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("A").ToString();
richTextBox1.Text = str;
```

But instead, the Rich text box on the form populates with this

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection
```

Do you know how I can get a list of links from the current webpage to show in the textbox?

Thanks
Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the HtmlAgility pack it's easy:

```
HtmlWindow window = webBrowser1.Document.Window;
string str = window.Document.Body.OuterHtml;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HtmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlDoc.LoadHtml(str);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection Nodes = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");

foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode Node in Nodes)
{
    textBox1.Text += Node.OuterHtml + "\r\n";
}
```